# How can I get Openindiana built in samba to use an OpenLDAP server?

Tags: samba, openldap, openindiana

I built an OpenIndiana / NAPP-IT server to use for samba home shares. Up to now I had planned to use a KVM virtual machine to run the samba/ldap stack, then connect the vm to the ZFS volume thru iscsi. Unfortunately I am reading that iscsi LUN's aren't recommended for sizes up in the 4TB + range.

Alternatevely, I am faced with either NFS sharing the volume to the vm then making samba share it. I don't like the idea of mixing NFS and samba though. At least I don't think I like the idea. Never tried it. Otherwise, I guess I will have to get samba set up on OpenIndiana (which I hear handles ACL better) but how to get that samba to authenticate thru OpenLDAP?

Bottom line is I need to use the new NAPP-it box for my home folders (among other things). I would love to have the samba running on the NAPP-it box so the data goes straight there instead of bottlenecking it with a vm. But I have to make the LDAP connection somehow.

Comment: Where are you reading that about iSCSI LUNs?

Comment: Why not break the iSCSI target into multiple smaller LUNs, and then run something like LVM, or mdraid and make them into a larger contiguous block?

Comment: never thought of that. at first it sounded risky but i can snapshot it anyway. plus i should be able to snapshot the LUN volume too?

Comment: Er.  You should be able to do something like that, depending on your storage provider/target.

Comment: do you think i am squandering all the benefits of ZFS by doing this? i hate indecisiveness argg..

Comment: I really don't know that much about ZFS to be able to make that judgement call.